# How to add a Div into another Div

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I'm facing a problem in my html website.

This is what I see:
[image]

I want to add my face inside the grey box

Here is my html code:

```
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="profilePic"><img src="profilePic.png"></div>
    <div class="sideBar"></div>
    
    
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap');

*{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

}

.sideBar{
    width:345px;
    height:647px;
    background-color:#e4e3e3;


}

.profilePic img{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 100%;

}
```

If this is an easy solution please let me know.

Comment: You should put the whole div with class ProfilePic inside of the div with class Sidebar:

Comment: Let me try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap');

*{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

}

.sideBar{
    width:345px;
    height:647px;
    background-color:#e4e3e3;


}

.profilePic img{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 100%;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sideBar"><img src="profilePic.png"></div>
    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just update your markup to this**

```
<div class="sideBar">
     <div class="profilePic"><img src="profilePic.png"></div>
</div>
```